# creating a shared_ptr from unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, smart-pointers, clang++

In a piece of code I reviewed lately, which compiled fine with `g++-4.6`, I encountered a strange try to create a `std::shared_ptr` from `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo...
std::make_shared<Foo>(std::move(foo));
```

This seems rather odd to me. This should be `std::shared_ptr<Foo>(std::move(foo));` afaik, though I'm not perfectly familiar with moves (and I know `std::move` is only a cast, nothing get's moved).

Checking with different compilers on this SSC(NUC*)E

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
   std::unique_ptr<int> foo(new int);
   std::make_shared<int>(std::move(foo));
}
```

Results of compilation:

- g++-4.4.7     gives compilation error
- g++-4.6.4     compiles without any error
- g++-4.7.3     gives **internal compiler error**
- g++-4.8.1     gives compilation error
- clang++-3.2.1 compiles without any error

So the question is: which compiler is right in terms of the standard? Does the standard require this to be an invalid statement, a valid statement or is this simply undefined?

**Addition**

We've agreed on that some of these compilers, such as clang++ and g++-4.6.4, permit the conversion while they shouldn't. However with g++-4.7.3 (which produces an internal compiler error on `std::make_shared<Foo>(std::move(foo));`), correctly rejects `int bar(std::move(foo));`

Because of this huge difference in behavior, I'm leaving the question as it is, although part of it would be answerable with the reduction to `int bar(std::move(foo));`.

---

*) NUC: Not universally compilable

Comment: Unless `Foo` has a constructor that takes a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` it shouldn't compile.

Comment: it's confusing saying "compiles with correct error" when you mean "doesn't compile". And the question title is confusing, you're not creating a shared_ptr from a unique_ptr, you're creating an `int` from a unique_ptr.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I adjusted the formulation. However I will leave the title as it is. Why? The intent of the developer was to create a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` that way. It is not the point of this question to create an `int` from a `unique_ptr`, but why different compilers allow this statement or fail miserably.

Comment: just for a reference I checked whether `unique_ptr` is implicitly convertible to a normal pointer (but it isn't)

Comment: @Alex and it shouldn't be. This would break the concept of `*unique*_ptr`

Comment: Why don't you simply use release: `std::unique_ptr<int> foo(new int); std::shared_ptr<int> shptr(foo.release());`? (It is not compiler bug.)

Comment: @Naszta Yes, that was my first reading of the question. The point is, the line `std::make_shared<int>(std::move(foo));` should not compile. That is the real question whether the standard allows it. In my opinion, it is a compiler bug.

Comment: @Naszta As I've said, it wasn't _my_ code and the intent was to make a pointer shared from unique. The correct way is via the shared_ptr ctor which takes a unique_ptr. The incorrect way shown here produces a variety of different behaviour in compilers, some of which are wrong.

Comment: @Naszta Do not write `std::shared_ptr<int> shptr(foo.release());`! This is dangerous code that can cause a memory leak. If `shared_ptr` fails to allocate its reference block and throws an exception you now have leaked memory.

Comment: @Simple this will not be a memory leak. the cpp reference says that in case of bad_alloc exception the delete ptr will be called

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does C++11 unique\_ptr and shared\_ptr able to convert to each other's type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884728/does-c11-unique-ptr-and-shared-ptr-able-to-convert-to-each-others-type)

Comment: I got my answer seven years ago, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**UPDATE 2:** This [bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17295) has been fixed in Clang in r191150. GCC rejects the code with a proper error message.

---

**UPDATE:** I have submitted a [bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17295). The following code on my machine with clang++ 3.4 (trunk 191037)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
   std::unique_ptr<int> u_ptr(new int(42));

   std::cout << " u_ptr.get() = " <<  u_ptr.get() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "*u_ptr       = " << *u_ptr       << std::endl;

   auto s_ptr = std::make_shared<int>(std::move(u_ptr));

   std::cout << "After move" << std::endl;

   std::cout << " u_ptr.get() = " <<  u_ptr.get() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "*u_ptr       = " << *u_ptr       << std::endl;
   std::cout << " s_ptr.get() = " <<  s_ptr.get() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "*s_ptr       = " << *s_ptr       << std::endl;
}
```

prints this:

```
 u_ptr.get() = 0x16fa010
*u_ptr       = 42
After move
 u_ptr.get() = 0x16fa010
*u_ptr       = 42
 s_ptr.get() = 0x16fa048
*s_ptr       = 1
```

As you can see, the `unique_ptr` hasn't been moved from. The standard *guarantees* that it should be null after it has been moved from. The `shared_ptr` points to a wrong value.

The weird thing is that it compiles without a warning and valgrind doesn't report any issues, no leak, no heap corruption. Weird.

The proper behavior is shown if I create `s_ptr` with the `shared_ptr` ctor taking an rvalue ref to a `unique_ptr` instead of `make_shared`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
   std::unique_ptr<int> u_ptr(new int(42));

   std::cout << " u_ptr.get() = " <<  u_ptr.get() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "*u_ptr       = " << *u_ptr       << std::endl;

   std::shared_ptr<int> s_ptr{std::move(u_ptr)};

   std::cout << "After move" << std::endl;

   std::cout << " u_ptr.get() = " <<  u_ptr.get() << std::endl;
   //std::cout << "*u_ptr       = " << *u_ptr       << std::endl; // <-- would give a segfault
   std::cout << " s_ptr.get() = " <<  s_ptr.get() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "*s_ptr       = " << *s_ptr       << std::endl;
}
```

It prints:

```
 u_ptr.get() = 0x5a06040
*u_ptr       = 42
After move
 u_ptr.get() = 0
 s_ptr.get() = 0x5a06040
*s_ptr       = 42
```

As you see, `u_ptr` is null after the move as required by the standard and `s_ptr` points to the correct value. This is the correct behavior.

---

*(The original answer.)*

[As Simple has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889843/creating-a-shared-ptr-from-unique-ptr#comment27880996_18889843): "Unless Foo has a constructor that takes a std::unique_ptr it shouldn't compile."

To expand on it a little bit: [`make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) forwards its arguments to T's constructor. If T doesn't have any ctor that could accept that `unique_ptr<T>&&` it is a compile error.

However, it is easy to fix this code and get what you want ([online demo](http://ideone.com/cpx3vM)):

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class widget { };

int main() {

    unique_ptr<widget> uptr{new widget};

    shared_ptr<widget> sptr(std::move(uptr));
}
```

The point is: `make_shared` is the wrong thing to use in this situation. `shared_ptr` has a ctor that accepts an `unique_ptr<Y,Deleter>&&`, see [(13) at the ctors of `shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr).

Comment: @stefan Sorry, I misunderstood your question. It took me 5 more minutes to understand the real problem here. Please check my updated answer. I will get back to you later today with the results obtained with the latest clang.

Comment: It's a very good answer now exploring the misbehaviour of clang. Thank you for that!

Comment: It turns out that `g++-4.6.4` permits the intermediate use of `operator bool()` to first convert from `unique_ptr<T>` to `bool` to `int`. Probably, clang++ does the same.

Comment: @stefan Thanks for the info. Please give some time, I will check the latest clang. In my opinion, the line `std::make_shared<int>(std::move(foo));` should not compile. If it does, it is a bug. By the way, where did you find this info?

Comment: @stefan By the way, +1 for the question, a very weird compiler bug.

Comment: I've just inserted a debug statement into the `operator bool()`, compiled and executed. The debug statement appeared, hence it was used. It's as simple as that. ;-)

Comment: Oh, I see. :) If you check my bug report, it has been confirmed by Richard Smith that it is a bug. Also, Jonathan Wakely is another prominent expert and compiler developer in the field. So, it *is* a bug.

Comment: I'm experiencing this with MSVC 12 (Visual Studio 2013) and the most suprising thing is that the code works! I mistakenly wrote code like this, but the content of the shared_ptr was fine. I don't understand it at all.

Comment: @AzP Yeah, early compiler versions had weird bugs in this situation. It is not worth wasting your time tracking down these bugs; most likely a newer version of the compiler does not suffer from this.

Comment: @Ali Yeah, for me it was actually an error, so I fixed my code instead.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar: auto const size = 5;auto up1array1 = std::make_unique<int[]>(size); std::shared_ptr<int[]> sparray(std::move( up1array1 ));...but it doesn't work. Wonder why!!

Answer (score 12):

This shouldn't compile. If we disregard the uniqueness and sharedness of the pointers for a moment, it's basically trying to do this:

```
int *u = new int;
int *s = new int(std::move(u));
```

It means it's *dynamically* creating an `int` and initialising it with an rvalue reference to `std::unique_ptr<int>`. For `int`s, that simply shouldn't compile.

For a general class `Foo`, it depends on the class. If it has a constructor taking a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` by value, const ref or rvalue ref, it will work (but maybe not do what the author intended). In other cases, it shouldn't compile.

Comment: Right, good answer. Interestingly there is still a difference between the smart pointer version and yours, as all compilers mentioned correctly reject your sample code.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a reduced example which clang incorrectly compiles:

```
struct ptr
{
  int* p;

  explicit operator bool() const { return p != nullptr; }
};

int main()
{
  ptr u{};
  int* p = new int(u);
}
```

Clang uses the explicit bool conversion operator to initialize the `int` (and the Intel compiler does too.)

Clang 3.4 does not allow:

```
int i = int(u);
```

but it does allow:

```
int* p = new int(u);
```

I think both should be rejected. (Clang 3.3 and ICC allow both.)

I've added this example to the [bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17295).

Answer (score 0):

Although counterintuitive it is perfectly allowed:

`std::shared_ptr<Type> shp = std::make_unique<Type>( arg );`