# Combing two factory methods returning unique_ptr and shared_ptr into one in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

Lets assume I have two factory functions, one returning `std::unique_ptr` and the other returning `std::shared_ptr`:

```
template<class T, class... Args>
std::shared_ptr<T> createObjectS (Args... args)
{
  // running some code
  return std::make_shared<T>(args...);
}
template<class T, class... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> createObjectU (Args... args)
{
  // running some code
  return std::make_unique<T>(args...);
}
```

Is it possible to combine these two functions into one using template meta programming?

Comment: How do you decide on the call-site which one to call?

Comment: I was trying to add a template parameter:  <class T, class PtrType = std::shared_ptr>, but it did not work.

Comment: Why do you need both? Why not just have the `unique_ptr` version since `unique_ptr` easily and efficiently converts to a `shared_ptr`?

Comment: @JamesAdkison • not entirely efficiently, in the sense of "as efficiently".  The make_shared can do both the bookkeeping and object in one allocation, but unique_ptr to shared_ptr requires a secondary allocation for the bookkeeping overhead.

Comment: @Eljay Both `make_shared` and conversion from `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr` will require creation of a control block. My comment is in the same spirit as the quoted text in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37885232/4505712). Is your point about the total number of dynamic allocations?

Comment: @JamesAdkison • correct, the overhead of a heap allocation far outweighs the bookkeeping constructor (can't say about the overhead of the held object's constructor... I've seen some really gnarly ones).

Comment: @Eljay For clarity, what do you mean by "bookkeeping"? I thought you were talking about the control block, which is dynamically allocated, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: @JamesAdkison • with `make_shared`, there is only one memory allocation.  A combination of the bookkeeping block along with the object footprint.  Depending on the objects and the cost of a memory allocation.  Which, granted, isn't "huge", but may be the biggest cost for small objects; for larger or complex objects, could be a drop in the bucket.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174759/discussion-between-james-adkison-and-eljay).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use SFINAE, but then I don't really see the point to have this inside a function anymore.  It's pretty redundant.

```
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, class... Args>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<T, std::shared_ptr<typename T::element_type>>::value, T>::type
createObject(Args&&... args) {
    // running some code
    return std::make_shared<typename T::element_type>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
template <class T, class... Args>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<T, std::unique_ptr<typename T::element_type>>::value, T>::type
createObject(Args&&... args) {
    // running some code
    return std::make_unique<typename T::element_type>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    auto s = createObject<std::shared_ptr<int>>(1);
    auto u = createObject<std::unique_ptr<int>>(1);
}
```

A little bit more compact but essentially the same idea with a scoped enum

```
#include <memory>

enum class ptr_t { shared, unique };

template <ptr_t P, class T, class... Args>
typename std::enable_if<P == ptr_t::shared, std::shared_ptr<T>>::type
createObject(Args&&... args) {
    // running some code
    return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
template <ptr_t P, class T, class... Args>
typename std::enable_if<P == ptr_t::unique, std::unique_ptr<T>>::type
createObject(Args&&... args) {
    // running some code
    return std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    auto s = createObject<ptr_t::shared, int>(1);
    auto u = createObject<ptr_t::unique, int>(1);
}
```

In C++17 you of course use `if constexpr` in both cases rather than SFINAE.

```
#include <memory>

enum class ptr_t { shared, unique };

template <ptr_t P, class T, class... Args>
decltype(auto) createObject(Args &&... args) {
    // running some code
    if constexpr (P == ptr_t::shared) {
        return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } else if (P == ptr_t::unique) {
        return std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just drop the `shared_ptr` one since the `unique_ptr` is convertible to an `shared_ptr`. `std::shared_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_unique<int>();`.

Comment: @tkausl Thank you, I wasn't aware that this conversion exists.  However, I am literally answering the question here, how to combine those functions into one.

Comment: I like the enum tag version. If you put the type parameter first and the tag parameter second, the tag parameter could have a default template argument, in case the code base is going to use one much more often than the other. Though there's also a plus to forcing the coder to think about which is better.

Comment: @HenriMenke Is there a way to get a concise version (like C++17, constexpr solution) using only C++14 features?

Comment: @motam79 Not really,  you could use explicit template specializations instead of SFINAE: https://hastebin.com/raw/lefofewoha

Comment: @motam79 The partial template specialization also let you easily define a default pointer type to return: https://hastebin.com/ofodabesed.cpp

Answer (score 1):

With specialization, you may do:

```
template <typename T> struct FactoryImpl;

template <typename T> struct FactoryImpl<std::unique_ptr<T>>
{
    template <typename ... Ts>
    auto operator ()(Ts&&... args) const
    {
        return std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }
};

template <typename T> struct FactoryImpl<std::shared_ptr<T>>
{
    template <typename ... Ts>
    auto operator ()(Ts&&... args) const
    {
        return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }
};

template<class T, class... Ts>
auto createObjectS (Ts&&... args)
{
    return FactoryImpl<T>{}(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

with usage:

```
auto s = createObject<std::shared_ptr<MyObject>>(42);
auto u = createObject<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>>(42);
```