# Constructing shared_ptr from unique_ptr with and without move?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I see in the highly-upvoted answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37885232/3754760) there are two ways to convert a unique_ptr to a shared_ptr, namely by creating the unique_ptr first and then `move`-ing it to the shared_ptr, as well as assigning the unique_ptr directly to the shared_ptr.

Example:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::string> unique = std::make_unique<std::string>("test");
std::shared_ptr<std::string> shared = std::move(unique);
```

or:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> shared = std::make_unique<std::string>("test");
```

Are the two above equivalent, performance-wise? Secondly, I see a warning like `Moving a temporary object prevents copy elision` when doing something like this:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> shared = std::move(std::make_unique<std::string>("test"));
```

As someone pretty new to smart pointers, could someone explain what this warning means and why it occurs in the 3rd example? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are the two above equivalent

Yes

> could someone explain what this warning means and why it occurs in the 3rd example?

[Copy Elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) only works when the result of a function call returning a temp object is *directly* assigned to a variable.  The compiler can optimize away the temp object and let the function initialize the variable directly. But in the 3rd example, there is an intermediate type-cast being performed between the construction of the temp object and the assignment of the temp object to a variable, so the temp object can't be optimized away.

Comment: I would add that std::make_unique already returns a temp objects (rvalue) so the std::move is logically wrong (and misleading the dev who will work with this code in a couple of weeks, probably always you)