# How can a simple std::cout << "---" << std::endl; alter how UB manifests?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, lifetime, destroy

### Some background

Today I saw, in the body of a function `kaboom`, a `local` `shared_ptr` pointing to a `*global` object and, being captured by reference *and* its pointee returned by reference by a lambda, i.e. `[&local]() -> auto& { return *local; }`; this lambda was stored somehow for further use after the function `kaboom` returned.

As soon as I saw this, I thought the code was invoking undefined behavior. I tried to make a minimal example to support my claim, and came up with the following.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

struct Resource {
    const int i{3};
};

std::shared_ptr<Resource> global = std::make_unique<Resource>();

auto getSharedStuff() {
    return global;
}

std::vector<std::function<Resource&()>> actions{};

void kaboom() {
    std::shared_ptr<Resource> local = getSharedStuff();
    actions.push_back([&local]() -> auto& { return *local; });
}

int main() {
    kaboom();
    std::cout << global->i << std::endl;
    std::cout << actions[0]().i << std::endl;
}
```

[The simple fact that the 2 `cout`s give 3 and 0 respectively](https://godbolt.org/z/oxhec5jc9) is proof for me that I'm observing UB (3 is correct, and 0 could have been anything, including 3, but I've been lucky that it was not 3, so the UB is well manifest).

Good.

### The code I'm curious about

But before getting there, an intermediate version of the repro above was this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

struct Resource {
    Resource(Resource const&) = delete;
    Resource(Resource&&) = delete;
    Resource() { std::cout << this << "'s ctor" << std::endl; }
    ~Resource() { std::cout << this << "'s dtor" << std::endl; }
    void operator()() { std::cout << this << "'s operator()" << std::endl; }
};

std::shared_ptr<Resource> global = std::make_unique<Resource>();

auto getSharedStuff() {
    return global;
}

std::vector<std::function<Resource&()>> actions{};

void kaboom() {
    std::shared_ptr<Resource> local = getSharedStuff();
    actions.push_back([&local]() -> auto& { return *local; });
}

int main() {
    kaboom();
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    actions[0]()();
}
```

[which can result in this output](https://godbolt.org/z/G81nzaGYY)

```
0xc602b0's ctor
---
0x7f0f48f7f4a0's operator()
0xc602b0's dtor
```

I'm kind of ok with this, as `actions[0]()()` is dereferencing a destroyed `shared_ptr` and calling `operator()` on the screwed up result, so I accept that `this` can be screwup too.

What's funny, though, is that [removing `std::cout << "---" << std::endl;`](https://godbolt.org/z/61K9hncT5) makes UB less manifest, as the output becomes something like this:

```
0xce92b0's ctor
0xce92b0's operator()
0xce92b0's dtor
```

So my question is: how can a "simple" line as `std::cout << "---" << std::endl;` affect *this* way the manifestation of UB?

Comment: Undefined means it's pointless to try to make sense of it. Probably the extra line involves function calls that change the stack.

Comment: Justified or not, `std::shared_ptr<Resource> global = std::make_unique<Resource>();` compiling surprised the hell out of me.

Comment: Trying to find a reason your undefined behavior has a particular behavior is king of pointless as any change in the program could change the entire behavior.

Comment: @user4581301 Why is it that surprising? It is c'tor # 13 from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)

Comment: # 13, but I didn't know it existed until I looked it up. I'm not sure I like it. Being able to go from unique to shared so easily messes with my expectations.

Comment: It surprised me too, but it is a Good Thing.

Comment: @user4581301 Good quote for why the behavior is desirable here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37885232/4342498

Comment: Ah, the things you read, never take advantage of, and thus forget.

Comment: Unique to shared is okay.  Shared to unique would be bad.

Comment: @user4581301, Scott Meyers rules!

Comment: @Enlico Well I'll be damned. That's why he's so quiet these days. He's busy *ruling!*